# Ocaml: Recursion: intersection

Tags: recursion, ocaml

function name: intersection: takes 2 lists and returns list of all elements that appear in both

ie: [1; 2; 2; 3; 4; 4; 3] [2; 3] -> [2; 2; 3; 3]

```
let rec intersection (l1: int list) (l2: int list) : int list = 
    begin match l1, l2 with
      | hd :: tl, hd2 :: tl2 -> if hd = hd2 then hd :: intersection tl l2
                                            else intersection tl l2
      | _ -> []
    end
```

There is a problem with this code, but I'm not sure how to fix it - The code will run through and get [2; 2] because it keeps comparing to 2, the first element in l2, but I want l1 to also compare with tl2, does anyone have any suggestions?

```
 Should I add another match [], [] -> to clarify base case at the beginning?
```

Comment: How would *you* write it? What problems are you facing? Please show us your attempt or tell us about your approach. StackOverflow can offer you help with your homework, but we won't solve it for you.

Comment: Is there a more efficient way to implement this code? 

every other: Every 2nd element
ie: [1; 2; 3; 4; 5] -> [1; 3; 5]

     let rec every_other (l: int list) : int list = 
          begin match l with
               | [] -> []
               | hd :: tl -> hd :: every_other tl
           end

Comment: Or this one?

let rec all_even (l: int list): bool = begin match l with | [] -> true | hd :: tl -> (hd mod 2 = 0) && all_even tl end

Comment: Those are completely separate questions and should be posted as such, not as comments. However given they seem to ask about working code and how to improve it, they're offtopic on StackOverflow anyway, you'd better ask at [codereview.SE] about them

Answer (score 0):

> how do you refer to the first element in the other list?

Use another `match` statement:

```
let rec intersection (l1: int list) (l2: int list) : int list = 
    begin match l2 with
      | []         -> []
      | hd2 :: tl2 -> begin match l1 with
                        | []         -> …
                        | hd1 :: tl1 -> …
                      end
    end
```

You can also simplify this by omitting the `begin`/`end` parenthesis that are unnecessary in this case, and by matching upon a tuple right away:

```
let rec intersection (l1: int list) (l2: int list) : int list = match l1, l2 with
  | [],       _        -> []
  | hd1::tl1, []       -> …
  | hd1::tl1, hd2::tl2 -> …
```

<sub>(Disclaimer: I ignored the question whether looking at the two first elements in the same function is useful for implementing `intersection` at all)</sub>

Comment: Can you do begin match l1, l2 with | [], [] -> | hd1 :: tl1, hd2::tl2 or is that more inefficient?

Comment: or I could write a helper function like "contains" and then if contains is true, then hd1 :: intersection tl

Comment: Yes, you can do that, but don't forget to cover all four cases of empty/nonempty lists

Comment: Yes, a `contains` helper function sounds like a superb idea for `intersection`